# Javascript charting libraries for lines on coordinate plane

Tags: javascript, json, plot, coordinates, jqplot

What would be the easiest to use javascript (line) plotting libraries for data that looks like this?:

```
[ {"Name" : [1.5, 2.3]}, {"Name" : [5.6, 6.7]}, ... ]
```

Each "Name" => [x,y] pair. "Name"'s would be the labels. I have output that generates thousands of these points and I need to get them draw lines between them to illustrate a path.
I've looked into jqPlot, I'm not sure how if it would read the labeling and x,y coordinates correctly. Can someone demonstrate a simple implementation? Or recommend another solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think jqPlot would be fine.

Try looking here:

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html

From that link see under

Create a plot

Then, create the actual plot by calling the $.jqplot plugin with the id of your target and some data:

```
$.jqplot('chartdiv',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);
```

All you would have to do is to go loop through your JSON and make an array that looks like the one above.